# Question related to local class field theory: why if two map agree on the uniformizer then they are equal on $K^*$

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, class-field-theory, local-field

Let $K$ be a non-archimedean local field and $\pi$ a uniformizer of $O_K$. 
Suppose I have two continuous homomorphisms $\phi$ and $\phi'$ from $K^*$ to $Gal(K^{ab}/K)$. Suppose 
$\phi(\pi) = \phi'(\pi)$. Then how does it follow that $\phi = \phi'$?
Thank you!

(I am trying to understand the proof of Theorem 1.13 on page 24 of Milne http://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/CFT.pdf)

ps Here $K^{ab}$ is the union of all finite abelian extensions of $K$ in some fixed separable closure of $K$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what they have shown is that $\phi(\pi) = \phi'(\pi)$ for any two homomorphisms $\phi, \phi'$ **as well as for any uniformizer $\pi$**.

Then it follows, since any element in $K^\times$ can be expressed as a product of uniformizers.

Comment: Thank you! It wasn't clear to me when I first read it but it does seem to be the case!